# filter option is not in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I write `options{filter=true;}` in lexer grammar file and compile it with ANTLR4.
It said

```
 unsupported option 'filter'
```

It seems 'filter' only works with ANTLR3

I checked wiki http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Options and can not find the answer.
'filter' key word  is not in the source file
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/tool/Grammar.java
either.

How could I fix this？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `filter` option in ANTLR 4 lexer grammars. However, it is easy to mimic this behavior as follows:

```
lexer grammar L;

RULE
 : [a-zA-Z]+
 ;

FILTER
 : . -> skip
 ;
```

which is equivalent to the ANTLR 3 lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar L;

options {
  filter=true;
}

RULE
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
 ;
```